# WordPress: How can add posts without category into category

Tags: wordpress

I have some posts in my WordPress without category, Its above 2000 article, So i need to add this article into category that name is " News " by SQL

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = '3' WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '1';
```

The `3` is the id of the category "News", you might need to change it if it differs for you. The `1` is the category id for "Uncategorised", so the above should change all the post ids of 1 (Uncategorised) to 3 (News)

EDIT try:

```
 UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = '3' WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '';
```

Comment: thankx but the post not have any category, its not have any value

Comment: the post not have an record in wp_term_relationships, So we must insert record for all post that not have record in wp_term_relationships

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the answer to this question, so maybe it will be helpful for someone.
you can try this code, but instead 777 - add your category id

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships
(object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT 
    wp_posts.ID as object_id,
    777 as term_taxonomy_id,
    0 as term_order
FROM    wp_posts
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_term_relationships rel
ON      wp_posts.ID = rel.object_id 
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_term_taxonomy tax
ON      tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND tax.taxonomy = 'category' 
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_terms term
ON      term.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE   wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND term.term_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_category` SET `post_category` = '9' WHERE `post_category` = '';
```